# How to spoof cpu temperature for a VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, temperature

I am following some tutorials for writing Windows drivers and testing my results on a VirtualBox guest. One of the tutorials involves using the Win32 IOCTL to pass basic information about CPU core temperature to a user-mode application. I don't want to run this WIP demo driver on my bare metal to test if it can communicate in real time correctly, so how can I manually adjust the cpu temperature reported by VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

Per the answer SuperUser question below, it is not possible to fake a temperature:

https://superuser.com/questions/1374400/is-it-possible-to-fake-a-cpu-temperature-on-a-virtual-machine

Not sure how you're even getting a temp on a VirtualBox guest, as WMI (at least) under VirtualBox returns "not supported" for temp sensor queries.

Comment: That questions answer doesn't really fit either of our questions. His answer is stating that it's not possible to pass information about the bare cpu through to the guest OS, but our questions are asking how can we modify the sample information on the VM's virtual CPUs.

Comment: @JSONBrody You're correct that the summary I posted didn't answer the OP's question, so I've deleted it. The answer given in the link, however, is germane.

Comment: I disagree. His answer simply states that the virtual environment is not allowed to read from the physical sensors (paraphrased). When I init the driver I wrote, I do not get any indication for a lack of support. Rather, an unchanging constant is reported. It is due to this that I believe it is a set property of the virtual environment that should be trivial to set from some obscure VirtualBox configuration.